# Not able to use the dropdown feature of side navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [Admin Panel](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) it works fine when I am using it without some modification.
But when I make some changes like removing page-wrapper div inside the wrapper div, I am not able to use the dropdown feature and all collapsing links are active by default.

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-header -->

        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <em>Yesterday</em>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <em>Yesterday</em>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <em>Yesterday</em>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
        </ul>
        <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>



</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

Where am I missing something?

Here is how it looks like.

[image]

Comment: What 'changes' are you making that's making you notice it not working?

Comment: When I change my page-wrapper content, there is same error, but nabber looks fine for me.

Comment: There's probably an error in the code you are pasting, like a missing closing element or something.